# Cannot add additional fields to Devise Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

As the title says, I get an error undefined method when I try to add a column to the user.

Ruby - 2.3 Rails - 4.2.5 I'm using c9 as a cloud IDE.

What I do is to first: "rails g migration AddFieldsToUsers"

Then I add that into the DB:

```
class AddFieldsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
add_column :users, :username, :string
add_column :users, :current_goals, :text
add_column :users, :achieved_goals, :text
end
end
```

I run "rake db:migrate"

I create a registration_controller.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

private

def sign_up_params
params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end

def account_update_params
params.require(:user).permit(:current_goals, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
end
end
```

I add that into the routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
```

I add the appropriate fields to the views, and when I open up the "users/edit" page, I get this error:

```
undefined method `current_goals' for #User:0x00000004e892f8
Did you mean? current_password
```

I've tried this twice on two projects, and I got the same error.

Comment: You have to configure the strong parameters for `devise`. See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

Comment: Please format your code to make it easier to understand. Also, you might eliminate the scrolling of code.

Comment: Could you check your `db/schema.rb` and see if the new fields were added to the users table?

Comment: On another note, your controller name should be `registrations_controller.rb` not `registration_controller.rb`

Comment: @ArunKumar I've already configured the strong parameters in my ApplicationController

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:username, :current_goals])
  end
end

Comment: @oreoluwa Actually, the new fields weren't added to the DB. I've added them manually, but it still didn't work out.

Comment: @oreoluwa That was a typo. The name of the controller is registrations_controller.rb

Comment: @SvetoslavTodorov Did you add a `before_action` in the `ApplicationController`? `before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?`

Comment: Yes, I've added a before action @ArunKumar

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what you meant by adding it manually? Did you add it to the schema.rb or your opened up the db to add it?

Comment: @oreoluwa By adding it manually, I meant that I opened the schema.rb and wrote down: "t.text   "current_goals",                  default: "", null: false"

But it seems that whenever I run rake db:migrate it automatically removes it.

Comment: However, it is there in AddFieldsToUsers DB.

Comment: You shouldn't have to add it! Could you check if the timestamp on your schema is greater than that on the `AddFieldsToUsers` migration

Comment: They are the same.

Comment: I just did a similar test on my laptop, running Linux, and I followed the tutorial just as it said, and I didn't change anything, and I still get the same error.

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Also, the current_goals still didn't appear in the schema.db